# How to move screen from left to right through animation?

Tags: android

i am implementing one app related to animation.

My require ment is,

i have two buttons like next and previous.

I aranged these two buttons on the bottem of my screen.

I am showing some info on my screen.when user clickes the previous button or next button.

I want to show move the screen from one side to another side.

And modifi the info and display it again on the same screen.

if any one know how to move the screen from one side to another side

please help me

thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is `ViewPager`. Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html .

Comment: Also check : http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

Comment: if the answer is helpful, please approve.

Answer (score 1):

[ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) with an attached animation is your friend. Alternatively you can, as Akhil suggest, use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) from the support library.